# Angular, how to sort the translated values of array

Tags: angular

In my angular 6 application I have an array like this:

```
0:"SINGLE_VISION"
1:"PROGRESSIVE"
2:"BIFOCAL"
3:"DEGRESSIVE"
4:"FILTER"
```

and it is displayed in a mat-select with a translation pipe (ngx-translate).

```
<mat-select placeholder="placeholder" formControlName="type"> 
 {{ type | translate}} </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

now the array is sort by original values, but I want to sort by the translated values ( and to maintain the original valus inside the array).

So my array remains as it is but if I open the mat-select I see the translations in the correct order.

Are there a smart way to do this?

Comment: Maybe when you're initializing the array, you can directly translate the values then sort the array? With TranslateService, you can use this.translate.instant('XXX') to directly translate.

Comment: I need to maintain the original array

Comment: can you put the entire code for <mat-select> element ?

Answer (score 7):

You can create a `pipe` to sort your array. You'll sort regarding the translation of each value, using the `instant()` function from `TranslateService`:

```js
import { Pipe }             from '@angular/core';
import { PipeTransform }    from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderTranslate'
})
export class OrderTranslatePipe implements PipeTransform
{
  constructor(private translate : TranslateService) {}

  transform(array: Array<string>): Array<string>
  {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) =>
    {
      if (this.translate.instant(a) < this.translate.instant(b))
        return -1;
      else if (this.translate.instant(a) > this.translate.instant(b))
        return 1;
      else
        return 0;
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

And use it in your `mat-select`:

```js
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Test">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let v of values | orderTranslate" [value]="v">
      {{ v | translate }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort` mutates the original array, which cannot be used in every circumstance. Use `let sortedArray = array.slice().sort(...)` and you're good to go.